# How to use variables inside functions in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to use e.g. in line like this

```sql
SELECT  trunc(dateadd(month,mon,add_months(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), -9))) as dates
FROM    months
```

instead of -9, I would like to have there maximum value of column created like this (so in this case 12):

```sql
with months as (
    select 1 as mon union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
    select 5 as mon union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
    select 9 as mon union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
```

Is it possible somehow in Redshift? I tried just like that

```sql
SELECT  trunc(dateadd(month,mon,add_months(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), -MAX(mon))) as dates
FROM    months
```

but it is not working as expected

Comment: where is this `mon` field created? what if you create a column in the master table with the max value of the `mon` column and then use the resulting column in the function -- would that help?

Comment: What are you actually wanting to accomplish (as opposed to _how_ you are trying to do it)? Are you wanting a date from 9 months ago? Can you describe the output you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an alternate way is

```
  With data as
  (Select row_number()  over (order by 1) rn from 
  table)
 Select datediff(month, max(rn), current_date) 
  from data;
```

You can take some bigger table having more entries as required and replace that tablename in WITH clause like you said max 9 in above case and just limit them to the count of your tables month entries